# /proc/uptime の値を使って SNMP プライベート MIB を実装するときの SYNTAX として Counter64 は適切か？

Tags: linux, snmp

## 環境

- Ubuntu 18.04 ( 32 ビットと 64 ビット )
- net-snmp
- SNMP v2

## 前提

SNMP には hrSystemUptime [RFC 2790 - Host Resources MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790) が定義されていますが、hrSystemUptime は約 497 日で 0 に戻ってしまいます(1/100 秒 ごとに 1 カウントアップされる。4294967295 / 100 / 3600 / 24 => 497)

## 対策

そこで /proc/uptime から得られる値を使おうと考えています。以下のように出力される 2 つの値のうち左側を使います。

```
% cat /proc/uptime
24939.24 78721.83
```

なお uptime コマンドも /proc/uptime の値を使っているようです( https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/uptime.c#L47 https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/sysinfo.c#L106 )。

そして、プライベート MIB を新規に追加し、MIB の SYNTAX は Counter64 として定義しようと考えています。

Linux の実装では /proc/uptime の左側の値は tv_sec で取得され、 unsigned long で出力されています( [linux/uptime.c at master · torvalds/linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/uptime.c) )。64 ビット CPU の場合 unsigned long は 64 ビットであり、SNMP を実装する場合 64 ビットの値を表現できるのは Counter64 のみです。

## 質問

- /proc/uptime の値は 0 から繰り上がるとはいえ、時間を扱う目的のために Counter64 を使うのは適切なのでしょうか？(好きに実装すればよい？)
- Counter64 は 32 ビット CPU の Linux 上でも 64 ビットとして扱われるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己レス

## 時間を扱う目的のために Counter64 を使うのは適切か？

yes

RFC 2578 7.1.10.  Counter64 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-7.1.10 には

- インクリメントされる値に使う
- 0 にラップアラウンドされる

としか書かれていない。

## Counter64 は 32 ビット CPU の Linux 上でも 64 ビットとして扱われるのか？

yes

snmp_set_var_value() には ASN_COUNTER64 という値が使われている。

https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/code/ci/master/tree/snmplib/snmp_client.c#l968

value に struct counter64 を設定する実装となっているので、snmp_set_var_value() には struct counter64 を渡す。

struct counter64 は asn1.h に定義されている。

https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/code/ci/master/tree/include/net-snmp/library/asn1.h#l79

```
struct counter64 {
    u_long          high;
    u_long          low;
};
```

u_long は unsigned long

- 32ビット環境なら 4 バイト(32ビット)
- 64ビット環境なら 8 バイト(64ビット)